# android.net.wifi.STATE_CHANGE or android.net.wifi.supplicant.CONNECTION_CHANGE

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-broadcastreceiver

In android broadcasts, what's the difference between

```
 <action android:name="android.net.wifi.STATE_CHANGE"/>
```

and

```
 <action android:name="android.net.wifi.supplicant.CONNECTION_CHANGE" />
```

Comment: Read [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager) official document of android.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**STATE_CHANGE :**
Broadcast intent action indicating that the state of Wi-Fi connectivity has changed. An extra provides the new state in the form of a [NetworkInfo](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/NetworkInfo) object.

This is lookup key for an int that indicates whether Wi-Fi is enabled, disabled, enabling, disabling, or unknown.

**CONNECTION_CHANGE :**
Broadcast intent action indicating that a connection to the supplicant has been established (and it is now possible to perform Wi-Fi operations) or the connection to the supplicant has been lost. One extra provides the connection state as a boolean, where true means CONNECTED.

This is a lookup key for a boolean that indicates whether a connection to the supplicant daemon has been gained or lost. {@code true} means a connection now exists.

**P.S: SUPPLICANT_CONNECTION_CHANGE_ACTION is deprecated from API level P**

Comment: How can I get the extra NetworkInfo object. What I want is to know which SSID is disconnected

Comment: you mean, you need to know when the device get connected or disconnected from network state(net is available or not)?

Comment: I want to start an activity when a particular SSID is disconnected.
I tried  NetworkInfo networkInfo = intent.getParcelableExtra(WifiManager.EXTRA_NETWORK_INFO);
in broadcastreceiver.
networkInfo object returns <unknownssid>

Comment: tyy like this? cause EXTRA_NETWORK_INFO is deprecated. `ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) myContext.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
NetworkInfo activeNetwork = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();`

Comment: that is because no default network is currently active

Comment: I don't know why they removed EXTRA_NETWORK_INFO. That was giving me all states like connected, connecting, disconnected, authenticating..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171052/discussion-between-sam-and-yesudass-moses).

Answer (score 3):

**`<action android:name="android.net.wifi.STATE_CHANGE"/>`**

> Broadcast intent action indicating that the state of Wi-Fi
>   connectivity has changed.

**`<action android:name="android.net.wifi.supplicant.CONNECTION_CHANGE" />`**

> Broadcast intent action indicating that a connection to the supplicant
>   has been established (and it is now possible to perform Wi-Fi
>   operations) or the connection to the supplicant has been lost.

**Note:**

> This constant was deprecated in API level P. **This is no longer
>   supported.**

Answer (score 0):

The **android.net.wifi.supplicant.CONNECTION_CHANGE** action was sends a broadcast when the network is connected, 
but usually before the device has an IP address, so we needed the android.net.wifi.STATE_CHANGE action for that.

The **android.net.wifi.STATE_CHANGE** action receives a broadcast on disconnect only if the device is disconnecting from a network, but wifi is still enabled (when hotspot goes out of range, for example)

For more information see android developers officialsite https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager#SUPPLICANT_CONNECTION_CHANGE_ACTION